# Simple injector Web API integration package for .NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, simple-injector

When integrating simple injector in to a pure .net core web api project, should I still use the "ASP.NET Core MVC Integration NuGet package"? I was expecting to find a separate integration package similar to older .net versions. Or is `SimpleInjector.Integration.WebApi` intended to be used for .net core as well?

Comment: @mjwills The reason I posted the question is because would like an answer from a credible source regarding how the framework is indented to be used.

Comment: What does "pure .net core web api project" mean? Are you creating Controller classes?

Comment: @Steven A new ASP.NET core web application with the API template. My point is that there is no .net mvc involved in my project, and the only integration package I could find for .net core was the "MVC integration", thus my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the introduction to ASP.NET Core, Microsoft created one unified model that integrates both MVC and Web API. They called this framework: ASP.NET Core MVC. This means that creating a Web API project, you use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.

This is why, when integrating Simple Injector with a ASP.NET Core MVC Web API project, you will have to use the `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC` or `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC.Core` package. Most likely, in your case, you should use the `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC.Core`, since it contains extension methods to register controllers, while `SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore.MVC` builds on top of the Core package and adds MVC Razor Tag Helper integration, which is something you won't need when creating a Web API.